# Javascript replace in a string

Tags: javascript, string, replace, replacewith

I am familiar with the "replace" method in javascript is not enough. Possibly is it for my project is also a better way, then I would be glad if you also tells me this.

I would need the following:

I have a string with the following content:

```
var address = 'Beethovenstrasse 1, 97080 Würzburg';
```

This should be converted to:

```
var addressNew = '97080/W%C3%9CRZBURG/Beethovenstrasse/1';
```

And another string

```
var address = 'Hitzelsbergstr. 84, 83233 Bernau';
```

This should be converted to:

```
var addressNew = '83233%20Bernau,%20Hitzelsbergstr.%2084';
```

To explain why I need this: I need to convert the addresses are in the form of the string "address" in a database. The new string "addressNew" are then part of a link, which starts on mobile devices or TOMTOM navigation NAVIGON and the address to the destination passes by.

Ever Thanks for your help

Comment: Why is Wurzburg capital in first while Bernau isn't? Also what's your basic try?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with `replace`. You'd use capture groups. You may or may not need to use a function as the second argument (why does 97080 get `/W` after it, but 83233 gets `%20`?). Give it a go. Read the docs.

Comment: The two addressNew seem to be in different format. Is that  correct?

Comment: What did you try so far? Also, are you certain that addresses will always comply to the pattern given?

Comment: Why do you need to convert them in such a way? do you need to parse them somewhere or what? Also, they are different.

Comment: @Amit Joki: The app "navigon" does not require this information in this way, the app "tomtom".

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: The app "navigon" does not require this information in this way, the app "tomtom". The strings are needed different. I have expressed something wrong with the variables. Let's say that the first string is "var addressNewNavigon" and the second "var addressNewTomtom".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
var address = 'Beethovenstrasse 1, 97080 Würzburg';
var parts = address.split(', ');
var newString = parts[1] + '/' + parts[0];
console.log(encodeURIComponent(newString));
```

This solution is very specific and does not handle other formats, but you should get some ideas.

Comment: That's a very good approach, now I have this only bring in the correct order.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "now I have this only bring in the correct order"?

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string based on spaces and than you can adjeust the order and repalce characters with %20

Comment: This is not easy, the addresse may also be in this form:
var address = 'Dr Hans-Kapfinger-Strasse 1, 94057 Bad Kötzing';
or
var address = 'Bahnhofstrasse 1, 80000 Munich';

Comment: but it will always be in the form (street) (street number) (code)(city) ?